# Build object accessor from array in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

Assuming I have the following array: `const props = ["category", "category_name"]` and the following object:

```
const obj = {
  category: {
    category_name: "some name",
  }
}
```

how can I built a property accessor based on the array, so that I can access: `"some name"`?

I know there is a method in [Lodash get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) in which you can pass in a path to get the object like `'category.category_name'` so a simple `props.join(".")` would work here. But I want to not use Lodash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good candidate for [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
props.reduce((acc, prop) => acc?.[prop], obj)
```

The `.reduce()` method iterates over each element in the array that it is called on and passes both the current element and the value that the previous invocation resolved to, to the next iteration.

It is basically equivalent to

```
let acc = obj;
for (let prop of props) {
  acc = acc[prop];
}
return acc;
```

I also added the [optional chaining operator (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) so that when the element can't be found, it returns `undefined` instead of throwing an error.

```js
const obj = {
  category: {
    category_name: "some name",
  }
};
const props = ["category", "category_name"];
const props2 = ["does_not_exist", "category_name"];

console.log(props.reduce((acc, prop) => acc?.[prop], obj));
console.log(props2.reduce((acc, prop) => acc?.[prop], obj));

// Without optional chaining operator

console.log(props.reduce((acc, prop) => acc[prop], obj));
console.log(props2.reduce((acc, prop) => acc[prop], obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `forEach` like that.

```js
const props = ["category", "category_name"]
const obj = {
  category: {
    category_name: "some name",
  }
}

function propertyAccessor(obj, props){
   let value = obj;

   props.forEach(name => value = value[name])

   return value;
}


console.log(propertyAccessor(obj, props))
```

Comment: thanks, yeah that would work but I gotta admit I was hoping for more of a one liner.

Comment: @Ivar I guess so ;) wanna do an answer?

Comment: @supersize why do you care about the line count?