# js / change nested object along path

Tags: javascript

I have an object with a large nesting.
I can change its content like this:

```
children.props.children.props.children = 'test'
```

I can do this:

```
children['props']['children']['props'].children = 'test'
```

I want to do this by having the path in a variable

```
let path = ['props','children','props']
```

I tried like this:

```
let path = ['props','children','props']
children[path].children = 'test'

let path = [['props'],['children'],['props']]
children[path].children = 'test'
```

But it doesn't work. Please tell me how can I use the "path" variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build object accessor from array in vanilla JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74016995/build-object-accessor-from-array-in-vanilla-js)

Comment: https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash#set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
let path = ['props','children','props'];

const obj = { props: { children: { props: { children: null } } } };

let context = obj;

for (const name of path) {
  context = context[name];
}

context.children = "test";

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to "expand" the object by using an iterative approach:

```js
const children = {
  props: {
    children: {
      props: {
        children: 'change me'
      }
    }
  }
};

const expandObject = (component, path) => {
  let ref = component;
  for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
    ref = ref[path[i]];
  }
  return ref;
};

let path = ['props', 'children', 'props'];

expandObject(children, path).children = 'test';

console.log(children);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Here is a recursive version that uses a depth:

```js
const children = {
  props: {
    children: {
      props: {
        children: {
          props: {
            children: 'change me'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

const deepAccess = (component, depth) =>
  (depth === 0)
    ? component
    : deepAccess(component.props.children, depth - 1);

const ref = deepAccess(children, 2);

ref.props.children = 'test';

console.log(children);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

As others have shown, you can reduce the path:

```js
const children = {
  props: {
    children: {
      props: {
        children: 'change me'
      }
    }
  }
};

const expandObject = (component, path) =>
  path.reduce((acc, path) => acc[path], component);

let path = ['props', 'children', 'props'];

expandObject(children, path).children = 'test';

console.log(children);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach will create objects along the path if they don't already exist:

```js
const obj = {a: { b: 'existing' }};

['a','c','d'].reduce((x,y)=>x[y]??={},obj).children = 'test'

console.log(obj)
```